# how to reload an aspx page within an iframe when click event triggers from the control within an iframe

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a webpage wherein I have an iframe and I am loading a separate webpage [aspx] say wb2.aspx within it. There is a button named add comment in wb2.aspx.  When the button is clicked a modal pop up will appear and it accepts some values and stores it in database. I am displaying the comments in wb2.aspx. Now my intention is soon after the comment is added the page must be refreshed and the newly entered comment must be visible. How  can I do this?

Comment: "Please help me out" and "Thanks in advance" are examples of what NOT to put into your post. It clutters the post and is unhelpful. We will help you out if you have a good question, not if you put "Please help" at the bottom of your post. I know it sounds nice to say "Thanks in advance" but the best thanks you can give anyone on this forum is an upvote or an accepted answer.

Comment: A google search on "javascript update parent from popup" will get you started.

Comment: @jsve..  Well I'l keep your words in mind from next time.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long search I got this answer..

```
string script = "this.window.parent.location=this.window.parent.location;this.window.close();";
        if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("REFRESH_PARENT"))
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(string), "REFRESH_PARENT", script, true);
```